# Can I instal Ubuntu from the command line?

Tags: installation, command-line, fonts

I'm trying to install Ubuntu.

I've done this a thousand times and usually it's fine. However, this time it has got the screen fonts all far too large. So I can't actually get the mouse to a lot of the buttons and options, making it impossible to install.

I've had some minimal success by rotating the display by 90 degrees which lets me get to a few options, but this (a) makes my head hurt and (b) only gets me so far.

So I'd like a way to install using the command line. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you have the same issues when installing Ubuntu Server (ie, the non-gui install wizard)? Once the Server-edition is installed, you could add the desktop features back through apt.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to install Ubuntu only using the command line. If you check on the ubuntu wiki [install methods page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/InstallMethods). Check the alternate cd who provide an expert mode installation.

> Expert mode is accessed by pressing F6 in the boot menu, to access "Other Options", and then F6 again to be presented with another menu. In this menu the first choice is "Expert mode". This causes the installer to ask questions about virtually everything it does. It's supposed to be powerful rather than friendly, so the developers don't pay a lot of attention to UI warts in this mode; however, it should at least work to the point where you can complete an installation. If you like, you can try playing around with non-default answers to the questions it asks, and make sure its responses are appropriate.